# what is the fastest way to toggle images by class

Tags: jquery, image

i have a list of image

```
<img class="onOff" src="/Content/Images/on.png" /> 
<img class="onOff" src="/Content/Images/on.png" /> 
<img class="onOff" src="/Content/Images/on.png" /> 
<img class="onOff" src="/Content/Images/on.png" /> 
<img class="onOff" src="/Content/Images/on.png" />
```

and i want to change the source of all of the images (by using the class selector .onOff so each of the above images changes to this:

```
<img class="onOff" src="/Content/Images/off.png" />
```

what is the most efficient way to changing all of these images through jquery?

Comment: How about use `<div>` instead of `<img>` and put your image into `background-image` CSS? Toggle the CSS class results different style (and different bg image)

Comment: Do you want to toggle them all, or just set them all to Off?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Prefix the class selector with the tag:

```
$('img.onOff').attr('src', '/Content/Images/off.png');
```

However, if you've got some context (such as a container `div`) you can add that too to improve performance:

```
 $('img.onOff', '#containerDiv').attr('src', '/Content/Images/off.png');
```

If this is just to change the image though, take a look at [CSS Sprites](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/).

Answer (score 0):

This is the easiest way:

```
$('.onOff').attr('src', function(src) {
    return src == '/Content/Images/off.png' ? '/Content/Images/on.png' : src;
});
```

Looks like you might be misusing the image tag though. If the images are for design/layout only, then you'd be better to use background-images. What context are you using these in?

Answer (score 0):

Call this javascript function

```
    function changeImage() {
        $(".onOff").each(
            function()
            {
                $(this).attr("src","/Content/Images/off.png");
            }
        );
    }
```

Comment: There's absolutely no reason to use `.each()` here.